# Creating Grid in as3

Tags: performance, actionscript-3, flash, optimization, lag

I am trying to make to grid to squares using as3.
I am using nested for loops to create the grid.

```
import flash.display.Shape;
import flash.display.MovieClip;    

var n=10;

var myClip = new MovieClip;
stage.addChild(myClip);

for (var i = 0; i < n * 10; i += 10) {
    for (var j = 0; j < n * 10; j += 10) {
        var _shape = new Shape;
        myClip.addChild(_shape);
        _shape.graphics.lineStyle(1);
        _shape.graphics.beginFill(0xcccccc);
        _shape.graphics.drawRect(i, j, 10, 10);
        _shape.graphics.endFill();
    }
}
```

I am applying Zooming and Panning Gestures on myClip. For this Grid size everything works fine. As soon as I increase the value of n, it starts lagging

My game requires a bigger grid. Please help

Comment: Do you actually interact with those Shapes elsewhere in your code, or is this purely for a background grid?

Comment: Vector graphics are expensive in FlashPlayer.  You may want to consider using a lower level GPU framework like Starling for the best performance.    You could also try caching `myClip` as a bitmap.  Without knowing the purpose of these squares and how they are used, it's difficult to give specific advice.

Comment: I'd suggest one big background rectangle, one set of vertical lines and one set of horizontal lines. That will reduce the amount of objects Flash Player has to deal with. Furthermore, if it is a mobile app, BadFeeling is correct, you won't get anywhere with vector graphics and need a GPU-enabled framework.

Answer (score 0):

I'll show some ideas as code, my AS3 is a bit rusty but perhaps it helps.

You can reduce the number of Shape instances or draw the vector based grid graphic to a Bitmap. Since you are zooming and panning it you'll want to smooth it. Depending on performance and how much you zoom you also may want to draw the bitmap at a higher resolution than initially used. See comments in the below.

```
import flash.display.Shape;
import flash.display.MovieClip;    

var n=10;

// do you actually need dynamic binding or a timeline in this?
// if not (also if you don't know what it means) do use the Sprite class instead
var myClip = new MovieClip;
stage.addChild(myClip);

// if you don't need individual shapes move this out of the for loop
// your logic with all of the shapes having the same origin suggests this might be so
var _shape = new Shape;
myClip.addChild(_shape);

for (var i = 0; i < n * 10; i += 10) {
    for (var j = 0; j < n * 10; j += 10) {
        _shape.graphics.lineStyle(1);
        _shape.graphics.beginFill(0xcccccc);
        _shape.graphics.drawRect(i, j, 10, 10);
        _shape.graphics.endFill();
    }
}

// then we can draw the grid to a bitmap
// since you are scaling it I'm drawing it a 300% resolution
var _bmd:BitmapData = new BitmapData(_shape.width*3, _shape.height*3, true, 0);
var _bit:Bitmap = new Bitmap(_bmd);
myClip.addChild(_bit);
_shape.width*=3;
_shape.height*=3;
_bmd.draw(stage); 
_bit.smoothing = true;
_bit.width/=3;
_bit.height/=3;

// and remove the vector shape so it won't be rendered
myClip.removeChild(_shape);
// if need be it can be redrawn later
```